# outlook 2013 change language on certain words

Tags: microsoft-outlook, language

I was wondering if there is still the possibility to change the language for a certain word.

### Example:

Dörte lives in New York.

I plan to change the language of `Dörte` to German.

In Outlook 2010 I had a option in the context menu:
[image: Outlook 2010]

Where do I find the same option in Outlook 2013?

Regards,

Marcus

Answer (score 0):

This is on **Review** tab on a ribbon. The **Language** button opens menu with **Set Proofing Language** option.

To set the language for a single word, just select it before choosing the language:

[image: Set Proofing Language]
(you can see the German word is ok in the second line because I selected the German language for it)

And then, just select the required language:

[image: Select the Proofing Language]

Comment: Hello, It does not fully answer my question. With your hint I can change the language but I intend to change the language for a single word. Do you mind adding a screenshot?

Comment: Updated the answer. You need to select the required word before selecting the proofing language.